# IIS 7.0 and 404.0 Not found error

Tags: iis, iis-7

I have a text file that I am trying to browse to using the browser `http://files.mydomain.com/test.txt` and I get a:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not found
```

I double checked and the text file does exist. When I add a test.htm file, I have no issues.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple quick ideas:

Ensure "txt" is a known/allowed MIME type (text/plain) in IIS - if it's not that will give you a 404.

Ensure the IUSRS account has read access to the file (although that should give you a 401 if not set).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a http handler for"*.txt" extension on IIS 7.